# Dynamic / Conditional Enumeration From Multiple Columns

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to figure out the best way to enumerate multiple columns into two rows. For example, the data below contains the aggregated number of employees for each position in a company, broken out by a full-time equivalent (FTE) status.

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
|   Position    | PositionSlot | PositionSlotDescrpition |  PD  |  P5  |  P6  |  P7  |  P8  |  P9  |  FT  |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
| 1-400400-0680 | NULL         | NULL                    | 7    | 1    | 2    | NULL | 1    | 18   | NULL |
| 1-400400-0041 | NULL         | NULL                    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1    |
| 1-400400-0660 | NULL         | NULL                    | NULL | NULL | NULL | NULL | 1    | 6    | NULL |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+------+------+------+------+------+------+------+
```

So for `Position 1-400400-0680`, there are 29 employees broken out as listed above.

I need to enumerate these aggregates to create a **sequential** `PositionSlot` for each `Position`, with respect to the FTE breakout.

- The total number of rows for each `Position` should equal the sum of the columns `PD, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, and FT`.
- The `PositionsSlotDescription` should be the original column names `PD, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, and FT`
- The `PositionSlot` should be  sequential numbering of these rows. **The ordering of the slot does not matter.** Thus `PositionSlot = 1` can belong to any `PositionsSlotDescription`
- The `PositionsSlotDescription` should be repeated /
  duplicated based on the number from the original aggregate.

For example `Position 1-400400-0660` has 1 for `P8` and 6 for `P9`. Thus, there should be 1 row with a `PositionSlotDescription` of `P8` and 6 rows with a `PositionSlotDescription` of `P9`, the the `PositionSlots` should be 1-7

**EXPECTED RESULTS**

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+
|   Position    | PositionSlot | PositionSlotDescrpition |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+
| 1-400400-0041 |            1 | FT                      |

| 1-400400-0660 |            1 | P8                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            2 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            3 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            4 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            5 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            6 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            7 | P9                      |

| 1-400400-0680 |            1 | P5                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            2 | P6                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            3 | P6                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            4 | P8                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            5 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            6 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            7 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            8 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            9 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           10 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           11 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           12 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           13 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           14 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           15 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           16 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           17 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           18 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           19 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           20 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           21 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           22 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           23 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           24 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           25 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           26 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           27 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           28 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           29 | PD                      |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

**TEST SCRIPTS**

```
declare @table table (  Position varchar(64)                  --UniqueIdentifier
                        ,PositionSlot int                     
                        ,PositionSlotDescrpition varchar(64)
                        ,PD varchar(16)                  
                        ,P5 varchar(16)
                        ,P6 varchar(16)
                        ,P7 varchar(16)
                        ,P8 varchar(16)
                        ,P9 varchar(16)
                        ,FT varchar(16))    

insert into @table
values

('1-400400-0680',NULL,NULL,7,1,2,NULL,1,18,NULL),
('1-400400-0041',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1),
('1-400400-0660',NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,NULL,1,6,NULL)

declare @expectedResults table( Position varchar(64)
                                ,PositionSlot int               
                                ,PositionSlotDescrpition varchar(64))

insert into @expectedResults
values
('1-400400-0041',1,'FT'),
('1-400400-0660',1,'P8'),
('1-400400-0660',2,'P9'),
('1-400400-0660',3,'P9'),
('1-400400-0660',4,'P9'),
('1-400400-0660',5,'P9'),
('1-400400-0660',6,'P9'),
('1-400400-0660',7,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',1,'P5'),
('1-400400-0680',2,'P6'),
('1-400400-0680',3,'P6'),
('1-400400-0680',4,'P8'),
('1-400400-0680',5,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',6,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',7,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',8,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',9,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',10,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',11,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',12,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',13,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',14,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',15,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',16,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',17,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',18,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',19,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',20,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',21,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',22,'P9'),
('1-400400-0680',23,'PD'),
('1-400400-0680',24,'PD'),
('1-400400-0680',25,'PD'),
('1-400400-0680',26,'PD'),
('1-400400-0680',27,'PD'),
('1-400400-0680',28,'PD'),
('1-400400-0680',29,'PD')
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an adhoc numbers table along with `cross apply(values ...)` to unpivot your data:

```
;with numbers as (
  select top (32) --<-- 32 works for the example, increase for larger sets
      i=row_number() over(order by (select 1))
  from master..spt_values 
  order by i
)
select
    t.Position
  , PositionSlot=row_number() over (
      partition by t.Position 
      order by v.PositionSlotDescription, n.i
    )
  , v.PositionSlotDescription
from @table t
  cross apply (values 
    ('PD',PD),('P5',P5) ,('P6',P6) ,('P7',P7) ,('P8',P8) ,('P9',P9) ,('FT',FT) 
    ) v (PositionSlotDescription, Amount)
  inner join numbers n
    on n.i <= v.amount
where v.Amount is not null
order by t.Position, v.PositionSlotDescription
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/AMKCR70455

returns:

```
+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+
|   Position    | PositionSlot | PositionSlotDescription |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+
| 1-400400-0041 |            1 | FT                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            1 | P8                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            2 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            3 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            4 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            5 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            6 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0660 |            7 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            1 | P5                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            2 | P6                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            3 | P6                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            4 | P8                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            5 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            6 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            7 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            8 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |            9 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           10 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           11 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           12 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           13 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           14 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           15 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           16 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           17 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           18 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           19 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           20 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           21 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           22 | P9                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           23 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           24 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           25 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           26 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           27 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           28 | PD                      |
| 1-400400-0680 |           29 | PD                      |
+---------------+--------------+-------------------------+
```

---

Reference:

- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 1 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 2 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-2)
- [Generate a set or sequence without loops - 3 - Aaron Bertrand](https://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-3)
- [The "Numbers" or "Tally" Table: What it is and how it replaces a loop - Jeff Moden](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/T-SQL/62867/)

---

For larger sets, you can add `cross join from master..spt_values` to the `number` cte above, or replace the `numbers` cte with this alternate stacked cte:

```
;with n as (select n from (values(0),(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9)) t(n))
, numbers as (
    select top(50000)
        i=row_number() over (order by (select 1))
    from n as deka cross join n as hecto cross join n as kilo
                   cross join n as tenK  cross join n as hundredK
)
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/OZZHR43374

Comment: The small amount of time it took you to figure this up is impressive Zim.

Comment: @scsimon you included creation ddl and expected results, that made it pretty easy to get started. It is a fun problem, which helps too!

Comment: Ha, I agree! I was kind of shocked when I couldn't find anything on this, but maybe I was wording my question / thinking too complicated. I have a working solution, but it involves an unpivot and recursive CTE. I think I like your's better. I'm going to see if it scales. I expect it to. I'll post mine later for reference.

Comment: @scsimon if the number of iterations is small, the recursive cte shouldn't be a hindrance; otherwise I would guess that the recursion would underperform in comparison (similar to the results in the benchmarks in the Aaron Bertrand articles referenced in my answer).

Comment: I'll definitely let you know when I test this against the production numbers (that I haven't gotten back yet). I've read that article by Aaron, and most of his others. You're faster currently because I had to unpivot (posted below)

Answer (score 0):

An option with `UNPIVOT` and a recursive `CTE`

```
--Unpivot results
if object_id('tempdb..#unpivot') is not null drop table #unpivot
select
    u.Position
    ,u.Code
    ,u.Descr
into #unpivot
from
    @table t
unpivot
    (
    code
    for Descr in (PD, P5, P6, P7, P8, P9, FT)
    ) u


--Recursive CTE
;with cte as(
    select 
        t.Position
        ,Code = 1
        ,t.Descr
    from #unpivot t

    union all

    select 
        t2.Position
        ,cte.Code + 1
        ,t2.Descr
    from #unpivot t2
    inner join cte 
    on cte.Position = t2.Position 
    and cte.Descr = t2.Descr
    where t2.Code > cte.Code)

--Results
select 
    Position
    --,Code
    ,PositionSlotCode = row_number() over (partition by Position order by Descr) 
    ,Descr
from 
    cte
order by
    Position
    ,Descr
    ,Code
```